# libqt5webengine5 for 16.04

Tags: 16.04, qt5

I am trying to run an application which seems like to have `libqt5webengine5` as a requirement.
In the xenial repository I can only find `libqt5webkit`, but not `libqt5webengine`.

Where can I find it, is it even available for xenial?

Answer (score 2):

You can install it using Ethereum's ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ethereum/ethereum-qt
sudo apt install libqt5webengine5
```

[Here](https://github.com/QupZilla/qupzilla/issues/1956) I saw somebody complaining about problems occurred after installing `libqt5webengine5`, hence please be careful about which packages are going to be installed and which are going to be removed.

Comment: You might need to add the xenial proposed ppa as well, simply adding the ethereum-qt wasn't enough for me.

Comment: @ey.duh Could you tell me the error you got, please.

Answer (score 1):

A quick search at [Ubuntu Packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com) yields only [a result for Zesty Zapus (17.04)](http://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/libqt5webengine5), so no official package for 16.04